# Finding a close integer point to a line with irrational slopes

Tags: diophantine-approximation

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be two irrational numbers.

Is there a good way to find some integer $n,m$ that $|n\alpha-\beta-m|$ is sufficiently small?

For example, if $\beta=0$, we know that there exists $n,m$ that $|n\alpha-m|<\frac{1}{n}$ and this can be easily found by using continued fractions of $\alpha$.

Since $n\alpha$'s are equally distributed, I'm pretty sure that for 'most' $\alpha,\beta$ there   exist a $C_{\alpha,\beta}$ such that there exist infinitely many $n,m$ satisfying $|n\alpha-\beta-m|<\frac{C_{\alpha,\beta}}{n}$

Is there a good way to prove existence of such $C$ or some good heuristic algorithm on obtaining $n,m$?

Comment: Kronecker's theorem (the particular case in one dimension) says there are good approximations, but doesn't give the rate of convergence. So you're looking for an effective version of Kronecker's theorem in one dimension. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem